# Milk chocolate -> (eating or drinking)?

Tags: word-usage

Which one sounds natural to you?

> **A)** I'm **eating** milk chocolate.
>   **B)** I'm **drinking** milk chocolate.

Comment: When confused, for safety use "have" :)

Comment: Your title says "chocolate milk" but you wrote "milk chocolate" in the question. They are two different things. ;-)

Comment: In Chinese, we say "drink soup", but in English, we say "eat soup". That's the only time I've ever come across that ambiguity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## I'm eating *milk chocolate*.

[image: picture of milk chocolate]

---

## I'm drinking *chocolate milk*.

[image]

Comment: The only one I know who _drank milk chocolate_ was Augustus Gloop – and that [didn't turn out too well for him](http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.98644.1314089666!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/gallery_1200/gal-wonka-augustus-pipe-jpg.jpg) :-)

Comment: Given this is a learners' site, I really think you ought to give some further background as to *why* this distinction applies. So far as I'm concerned, it's much the same as the difference between [casserole meat](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080904010037AAL1TPN) and [meat casserole](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/casserole) (in each case the first "noun" acts as an adjective modifying the second, which really *is* a noun).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, they're certainly both modifier-head constructions.  Both words are nouns, in either case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Both words are nouns" there. It seems clear to me that in ***milk chocolate***, the word ***milk*** is an *adjective* modifying the noun ***chocolate***, to tell us what *kind* of chocolate. Just as in ***chocolate milk***, the first term is an adjectival usage telling us what kind of milk.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree that's worth expounding upon. You could do that in your own answer; that would make a nice complement to this one.